# Xamarin Label binding doesn't find DataContext

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, data-binding, label

Ok, so, I know this has been asked hundreds of times in one way or another, but none of those I found work out for me.

**Xaml:**
`<Label x:Name="valori"  Text="{Binding Path=Stats, Mode=TwoWay}"/>`

**C#:**

```
public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
    {
        public int Forza { get; set; }
        public int Intelligenza { get; set; }
        public int Sensibilità { get; set; }

        private string stats;
        public string Stats
        {
            get { return stats; }
            set
            {
                stats = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Stats));
            }
        }
        public Page1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            valori.BindingContext = this;

            Stats = $"Statistiche:  Forza={Forza}  Intelligenza={Intelligenza}  Sensibilità={Sensibilità}";
        }

    }
```

The only explanation Visual Studio gives me about it is, while hovering over "Stats" in Xaml,

> No DataContext value was found for the 'Stats' binding.

Comment: your page does not implement INotifyPropertyChanged, so calling OnPropertyChanged will not do anything.  Alterantely, you could just assign BindingContext after you set the value of your property

Comment: Are you unable to display the data?

Comment: Yeah, when I run the app, the string isn't there.

Comment: I run with your codes,but could not reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use .DataContext instead of bindingcontext? Not sure if this works

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't recognize DataContext as it does BindingContext, so I'm not sure it could help in any way...